# Qt GUI causes CPU overhead

Tags: qt, overhead

My code looks like this.
User press a key and gui is updated.
But, when user press a key continuously without releasing, CPU is stressed and the system freezes, until the GUI completes all the tasks ordered.

```
bool Reproductor::eventFilter(QObject * , QEvent * event)
{
    if(event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress)
    {

        int pressed_key_now = static_cast<QKeyEvent*>(event)->key();


        switch (pressed_key_now)
        {

            case Qt::Key_Asterisk:
            {
                // search in sqlite an update gui
                g_next_page_on_list_themes_down(); // <--- very heavy

                break;
            }
```

This is the view of the function profiler and the CPU overhead, that the continuos key press causes.
[image: function profiler]

Is it the QEventLoop that needs to be protected or changed?

Answer (score 0):

One way to easily combat this is to react on key release events instead of key press events.

If that's not possible for some reason you can always keep a flag yourself to indicate whether the user released the key in the meantime (eg. to identify a new, "fresh" key press event).